# PCA plot parameters

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pca

I am a beginner in python trying to create a 2 component PCA plot, using `pandas`, `sklearn.preprocessing`, `sklearn.decomposition`, and `Matplotlib.pyplot`.

My data frame is very large, relating to the characteristics of different species of plant, with many variables (>100 columns), and I would like to compare the effect of one of the characteristics/columns (stem length) on the variance of the data. The column for stem length consists of floats, ranging in size from 0 to around 75cm.

I would like to plot a PCA comparing the variance of characteristics when stem length >40cm and stem length <40cm. However I have no idea how to proceed with this.

I have been using the following website as a [guide for the PCA plot](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60).

I have already written the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("plant_data.csv")

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

plt.style.use("seaborn-darkgrid")

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, 
                           columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])
finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df[['stem_length']]], axis = 1)
```

How do I set the conditions for the parameters to be stem_length >40 and stem_length <40?

Comment: Do you want to add a new feature for stem length right?

Comment: I am not too sure - I don't fully understand the terminology involved as I am pretty much a complete beginner. A feature is essentially a parameter right? So when I create the plot, there will be one group of data points according to plants with stem length >40cm and another group of data points according to plans with stem length <40cm

Comment: @Billy do you understand what PCA method is used for?

Comment: when you plot the PCs, you are not "comparing the variance of characteristics" . If you look at the link you cited, the PCs would capture some ratio of the variance in your original data, but they are not variances

Comment: can you clarify what you would like to plot?

Answer (score 0):

The given dataset in the question link is called the "Iris Dataset". Considering that, and your working example with 2-principal components, you now have `finalDF` with three features (or dimensions, or columns - in excel).

Now, you need to define a feature, which can be acheived as:

```py
finalDF['stem_length_gt_40'] = finalDF['stem_length'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 40 else 0)
```

The code creates another column named `stem_length_gt_40` whose value is `1` if `stem_length > 40` else `0`.

Considering this, now you can perhaps plot `PCA-1 vs. PCA-2` and colour them differently based on `stem_length_gt_40` using `seaborn.scatterplot` as below:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plt.style.use("seaborn-darkgrid")

sns.scatterplot(x = 'principal component 1', y = 'principal component 2', data = finalDF, hue = 'stem_length_gt_40')
```

You can learn more about `sns.scatterpolt` over [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).